# Rails ajax call routes to wrong controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to use an ajax call to retrieve some data in Rails but it is getting routed to the wrong controller action.

route

```
  get 'articles/retrieve_articles' => 'articles#retrieve_articles'
```

controller

```
  def retrieve_articles
    test = "Testing"

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.json do
        render json: {
          data: {
              "test": @test
          }
        }
      end
    end
  end
```

ajax call to controller action

```
function getArticles() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "articles/retrieve_articles.json",
    xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
    }
  }).then(function(data){ 
    console.log("TESTING getting articles...");
  });
}
```

the log that shows it routed to the wrong function (it's going to the show action instead of retrieve_articles)

```
Started GET "/articles/retrieve_articles.json"
Processing by ArticlesController#show as JSON
[...]
Completed 404 Not Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Article with 'id'=retrieve_articles):
```

Comment: The order that you define your routes in routes.rb matters. Try moving the retrieve_articles route above the other one

Comment: ah yes of course, I forgot about the order of the routes.  That fixed it.  If you want to make this an answer I'll throw you some points.  Thanks!